# What index order does Opencv's cv::Mat::forEach<> function's position argument correspond to?

Tags: c++, opencv

I've  been trying to use opencv::forEach, but the position argument seems to correspond to the z,y,x, position, instead of x,y,z position.  I can't find this stated anywhere though, and OpenCV appears to imply the opposite in their [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a952ef1a85d70a510240cb645a90efc0d).

```
// Creating 3D matrix (255 x 255 x 255) typed uint8_t
// and initialize all elements by the value which equals elements position.
// i.e. pixels (x,y,z) = (1,2,3) is (b,g,r) = (1,2,3).
int sizes[] = { 255, 255, 255 };
typedef cv::Point3_<uint8_t> Pixel;
Mat_<Pixel> image = Mat::zeros(3, sizes, CV_8UC3);
image.forEach<Pixel>([&](Pixel& pixel, const int position[]) -> void {
    pixel.x = position[0];
    pixel.y = position[1];
    pixel.z = position[2];
});
```

I've looked this up outside of OpenCV's documenation, but apparently 99% of people don't use this for more than 1D matrices. I've seen no documentation state explicitly what order the position elements are in.  And OpenCV is not shy about using *either* natural, or C order indexing, the `at<T>` function for example supports both.

Answer (score -1):

Each pixel is stored in BGR format

Comment: Please elaborate.